# Disabling Linux kernel debugging option - lockdep for performance enhancement

Tags: linux, performance, linux-kernel, locking

In my custom environment, Linux kernel debugging functions such as `lock_acquire()` & `lock_release()` are consuming large number of CPU cycles limiting performance, canceling out the effects of many of the optimizations performed in the user space.

Apparently these functions perform book keeping for `lockdep` module as a debugging when developing kernel. So I am assuming if kernel config option [CONFIG_DEBUG_LOCK_ALLOC](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/lib/Kconfig.debug#L859) is disabled the kernel locks such as spinlock/mutex/rwlocks etc., where each lock/unlock using lock_acquire/release will compile to nothing.

Kindly let me know will this approach helps me in improving the performance and on what cost ?

Note: I am proposing this change only when the code runs in production environment and in house development can be done with enabling the option back.

Comment: IIRC, lockdep is rather controlled by CONFIG_PROVE_LOCKING and it is usually turned off by default already.